# How to share files/folders from the Windows 8.1 SkyDrive app?

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I want to share files like photos, or folders that contain the files, with others. I was trying to do this from the Windows 8.1 SkyDrive app, but I couldn't. Didn't see it anywhere at all in the app, no matter what I did. So, how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you can only do it from the Windows Explorer. Select the file you want to share in your SkyDrive folder, make a rightclick select share->SkyDrive.

[image]

You're now redirected to the SkyDrive site, here you can get the link and select who gets the permissions.